# decorating decorators in python

Tags: python, python-decorators

I am unable to understand how decorating decorators works in Python (2.7.2). I have following piece of code:

```
def verbose(function):
    print 'i am verbose and func is ' + function.__name__
    def wrapper2(func):
        print 'func is ' + repr(func)
        result = function(func)
        return result
    return wrapper2

@verbose
def more(function):
    print 'i am more and func is ' + function.__name__
    def wrapper1(*args, **kwargs):
        print 'args' + repr(args)
        result = function(*args)
        return result
    return wrapper1

@more
def hello(*args):
    print(sum(args))
```

when I run:

```
>>> hello(1,2,3)
```

this is what I get:

```
i am verbose and func is more
func is <function hello at 0x1015338c0>
i am more and func is hello    
args(1, 2, 3)
6
```

I am unable to visualize the sequence of calls that generates this output. I think the following call will still generate the same output and I am keen to understand how decorated decorators work in this specific example.

```
>>> verbose(more)(hello)(1,2,3)
i am verbose and func is more
func is <function hello at 0x101533d70>
i am more and func is hello
args(1, 2, 3)
6
```

Comment: Your code generates a NameError because you try to use the decorator before it is defined.  Do you actually have `verbose` defined above `more`?  Also, even if you do that, some of the output you show will be generated when `hello` is defined, and some when `more` is define, not when `hello` is called.  What is the `python>>` prompt in your example?

Comment: Fixed the name error. And yes, some part of the output is generated when I define `more` and some when I define `hello` methods. I am just pasting here to make sure that both ways of calling generate the same output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your reduction to `verbose(more)(hello)(1,2,3)` is correct.  However, those calls happen at different times.  Remember that this:

```
@deco
def func():
    # whatever
```

is the same as this:

```
def func():
    # whatever
func = deco(func)
```

So when you define `more`, `verbose` is called.  When you define `hello`, `more` (the decorated version) is called.  Your code is equivalent to:

```
def verbose(function):
    print 'i am verbose and func is ' + function.__name__
    def wrapper2(func):
        print 'func is ' + repr(func)
        result = function(func)
        return result
    return wrapper2

def more(function):
    print 'i am more and func is ' + function.__name__
    def wrapper1(*args, **kwargs):
        print 'args' + repr(args)
        result = function(*args)
        return result
    return wrapper1
more = verbose(more)

def hello(*args):
    print(sum(args))
hello = more(hello)
```

That should make it clear which function calls are happening when.  Note that neither `more` nor `verbose` are called when you *call* `hello(1, 2, 3)`.  The decorators are called when the decorated function is *defined* not when it is called.  At call time, what is called is the return value of the decorator (i.e., the functions `wrapper1` and `wrapper2` in your example).